# Sending a JSON object to local javascript in Android using evaluateJavascript

Tags: javascript, android

In my app I am loading a `html` page which is inside assest folder in Android. I want to send a `JSON object` to javascript function from Android `evaluateJavascript` method to load data in a map. I can pass a `string` value without a problem. But cannot pass a `JSON Object`. I guess this happen because of the `"` escape. But I couldn't find a way to solve it properly.

In Android.

```java
    final WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.sriLankaMap);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser(obj1));
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mymap.html");

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        view.evaluateJavascript("javascript: " + "updateFromAndroid1(\"" + obj1 + "\")", null);

    }
```

If I try to replace **obj1** with a string value then it will pass to javascript side.

Inside html...

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">

            function updateFromAndroid1(message){
                    $("#paragraph1").text(message);
            };


    </script>
```

This is the JSONobject...

```
    { 
       "district-Colombo":{ 
          "latitude":6.861198,
          "longitude":79.869869,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Colombo"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Gampaha":{ 
          "latitude":7.062374,
          "longitude":79.878003,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Gampaha"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Kalutara":{ 
          "latitude":6.604244,
          "longitude":79.982752,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Kalutara"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Mahanuwara":{ 
          "latitude":7.297609,
          "longitude":80.623034,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Mahanuwara"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Matale":{ 
          "latitude":7.592925,
          "longitude":80.615835,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Matale"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-NuwaraEliya":{ 
          "latitude":6.873037,
          "longitude":80.547327,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"NuwaraEliya"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Galle":{ 
          "latitude":6.225402,
          "longitude":80.084565,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Galle"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Matara":{ 
          "latitude":6.054305,
          "longitude":80.458447,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Matara"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Hambantota":{ 
          "latitude":6.181835,
          "longitude":80.954158,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Hambantota"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Jaffna":{ 
          "latitude":9.371795,
          "longitude":80.144216,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Jaffna"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Vanni":{ 
          "latitude":8.908094,
          "longitude":80.061819,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Vanni"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Batticaloa":{ 
          "latitude":7.849342,
          "longitude":81.287834,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Batticaloa"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Digamadulla":{ 
          "latitude":7.132633,
          "longitude":81.810863,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Digamadulla",
             "position":"left"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Trincomalee":{ 
          "latitude":8.634672,
          "longitude":80.950971,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Trincomalee"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Kurunegala":{ 
          "latitude":7.616318,
          "longitude":80.026354,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Kurunegala"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Puttalam":{ 
          "latitude":8.073188,
          "longitude":79.842825,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Puttalam"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Anuradhapura":{ 
          "latitude":8.396258,
          "longitude":80.195023,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Anuradhapura"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Polonnaruwa":{ 
          "latitude":8.07972,
          "longitude":80.858788,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Polonnaruwa"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Badulla":{ 
          "latitude":6.986406,
          "longitude":81.044426,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Badulla"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Moneragala":{ 
          "latitude":6.692467,
          "longitude":81.183383,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Moneragala"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Ratnapura":{ 
          "latitude":6.451828,
          "longitude":80.465478,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Ratnapura"
          },
          "href":""
       },
       "district-Kegalle":{ 
          "latitude":7.17907,
          "longitude":80.220945,
          "text":{ 
             "content":"Kegalle"
          },
          "href":""
       }
    }
```

Comment: I think you may need to serialize the jsonObject to String and deserialize the string to son object on the javascript side.

Comment: you should consider using com.eclipsesource.j2v8 and use the librarys v8 engine to run the javascript instead of a webview. Among other things this will allow you to send in an object to the javascript method, and also register a callback in android that can be called from the javascript when it is done with whatever job it is doing, including result parameters.

Comment: @JoachimHaglund how can i use this in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a workaround. This works, but I don't know whether this is correct or not.

Before I pass the string to the `evaluateJavascript` method,

```
String unescaped = fName.toString().replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

then

```
view.evaluateJavascript("javascript: " + "updateFromAndroid1(\"" + unescaped + "\")", null);
```

On the javascript side...

```
  function updateFromAndroid1(message){

  message= message.replace(/\\/g, "");

  var plots = JSON.parse(message);

  };
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

`evaluateJavascript` only accepts a `String` type, thus you have serialize the object to a string beforehand, and deserialze it on the client side:

- Java side:

```
...
view.evaluateJavascript(
    "javascript: "
    + "updateFromAndroid1(\""
    + obj1.toString()   // serialize to string repr
    + "\")", null);
...
```

- client side JS:

```
...
JSON.parse(message);  // deserialize with JSON.parse
...
```

Comment: Any error messages on Java/JS side? Thats supposed to work, but might run into undocumented restrictions. Steps to narrow it down:
- gets the object correctly serialized (debug on Java side)
- gets the JS function called at all - maybe try with a simpler/smaller object first

Comment: I updated with an answer. Please check it and tell me is that correct way of doing it.  **https://stackoverflow.com/a/59375328/10496250**

Comment: Oh well, yeah the '\' is cumbersome to escape here. This looks not quite correct, it seems that your backtranslation on JS can strip to much. Normally it should be enough to replace a single '\' with '\\', `evaluateJavascript` would deal with the correct back translation. Btw thats the point where an object aware interface simplifies things alot (a lib that does the low level stuff for you, as described by @joachim-haglund)

Comment: yes this also works **fName.toString().replace("\"", "\\\"");**

Comment: You should def. test this with some unicode chars, that will get printed as \u1234 in a JSON string to also correctly deal with the '\' (just saw that you only handle '"' atm).

Answer (score 0):

Example for using j2v8

in greadle add dependency 'com.eclipsesource.j2v8:j2v8:4.8.0@aar'

example usage:

```
V8 runtime = V8.createV8Runtime();
string MyJavascript = " if(5+params.someint==10){callback(true);}else{callback(false);}";

runtime.registerJavaMethod(callback, "callback");
runtime.executeScript("javascript:var params="
                    + MyJSONObject
                    + ";"
                    + MyJavascript);

runtime.release();
```

declaration of callback function:

```
JavaVoidCallback callback = new JavaVoidCallback() {
                public void invoke(final V8Object receiver, final V8Array parameters) {
                    if (parameters.length() > 0) {
                        Object arg1 = parameters.get(0);
                        boolean success = (boolean) arg1;
                        Log.d(TAG,"---------the callback returned: "+success);
                        if(success){
                            Log.d(TAG,"---------conditions true-------");
                        }
                        if (arg1 instanceof Releasable) {
                            ((Releasable) arg1).release();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

read more [here](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/getting-started-with-j2v8/)